Cannot update a component (`HotReload`) while rendering a different component (`PayPalButtons`)
I am creating an ecommerce website in Next.js and I am trying to integrate Paypal payment but every time I tried rending the payment modal box I get the following error:

Unhandled Runtime Error Error: Unable to render 
because window.paypal.Buttons is undefined.
Cannot update a component (HotReload) while rendering a different
component (PayPalButtons).

"In my current setup, where should I manage the state for PayPalButtons to ensure it doesn’t cause conflicts with other components?"
Here is the code:
"use client"
import React, { FunctionComponent, useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Header from '../Header';
import Container from '../Container';
import Footer from '../Footer';
import { VeeCartItem } from '@/types/types';
import useCartStore from '@/store/cart';
import { useShippingAddress } from '@/contexts/ShippingAddressContext';
import { ToastContainer, toast } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import Summary from './summary';
import Breadcrumbs from '../Breadcrumb';
import Image from 'next/image';
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation"
import {
    isUserLoggedIn,
    getUserData,
    redirectToLoginPage,
} from "@/auth/auth";
import { ApiRequestService } from '@/services/apiRequest.service';
import Spinner from '../Spinner';
import useAutoLogout from '@/hooks/useAutoLogout';
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js"
import {
    EmbeddedCheckoutProvider,
    EmbeddedCheckout,
} from "@stripe/react-stripe-js"
import {PayPalScriptProvider, PayPalButtons,  ReactPayPalScriptOptions } from '@paypal/react-paypal-js';


  const stripePromise = loadStripe(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY!); 



const apiUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL

const Payment = () => {


  const initialOptions: ReactPayPalScriptOptions = {
    clientId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID!,
    currency: "USD",
    components: 'buttons',
    intent: 'capture'
};


const { cartItems } = useCartStore();
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
const openOverlay = () => setIsOpen(true);

const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
const [totalFreightAmount, setTotalFreightAmount] = useState(0); 
const [totalWeight, setTotalWeight] = useState(0); 
const [transitDays, setTransitDays] = useState(''); 
const [errorIngramMessage, setErrorIngramMessage] = useState<string | null>(null);
const [loadingEstimate, setLoadingEstimate] = useState(false);
const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState("")
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState("");
const [backendResponse, setBackendResponse] = useState(null)
const [payPalOrderId, setPayPalOrderId] = useState("")
const [isPaypalOverlayVisible, setPaypalIsOverlayVisible] = useState<boolean>(false);
const [isOverlayVisible, setIsOverlayVisible] = useState<boolean>(false);
const [scriptLoaded, setScriptLoaded] = useState(false);
const [issubmitting, setIssubmitting] = useState(false);
const [sdkReady, setSdkReady] = useState(false);


const { push } = useRouter()

const closeOverlay = () => {
    setIsLoading(false);
    setIsOverlayVisible(false);
} 

const closePaypalOverlay = () => {
  setIsLoading(false);
  setPaypalIsOverlayVisible(false);
} 

    

      const expirePeriod =
    typeof window !== "undefined" ? localStorage.getItem("expire_period") : null;
    const expireTime = expirePeriod ? parseInt(expirePeriod, 10) : 0; 
    const isLoggedIn = useAutoLogout(expireTime);
    const overallSum = cartItems.reduce(
        (total, item) => total + item.price * item.quantity,
        0
      );




useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      const totalFreightAmountStr = localStorage.getItem("totalFreightAmount");
      const totalWeightStr = localStorage.getItem("totalWeight");
      const transitDaysStr = localStorage.getItem("transitDays");
  
      // Convert to number or use default values if not found
      const totalFreightAmount = totalFreightAmountStr ? parseFloat(totalFreightAmountStr) : 0;
      const totalWeight = totalWeightStr ? parseFloat(totalWeightStr) : 0;
      const transitDays = transitDaysStr || '';
  
      setTotalFreightAmount(totalFreightAmount);
      setTotalWeight(totalWeight);
      setTransitDays(transitDays);
    }
  }, []);


  
  const handleRadioChange = (event: { target: { id: string; }; }) => {
    const selectedOption = event.target.id;
    
        setSelectedOption(selectedOption);
    
};




const renderPaymentButton = () => {
    if (selectedOption === "card") {
        return (
    <div className="w-full flex center justify-center">
            <button
                className="mt-10 flex gap-2  justify-center rounded-md border border-transparent bg-primaryBg 
                py-2 px-4 text-sm font-medium text-white shadow-sm"
                type="submit"
                onClick={handlePayment} 
      disabled={isLoading}
            >
      {isLoading && <Spinner size="sm" />}
                        {isLoading ? 'Processing...' : 'Complete Payment'}
                
            </button>
    </div>
        )
    }else if (selectedOption === "paypal") {
        return (
    <div className="w-full flex center justify-center">
            <button
                className="mt-10 flex gap-2  justify-center rounded-md border border-transparent bg-primaryBg 
                py-2 px-4 text-sm font-medium text-white shadow-sm"
                type="submit"
                onClick={handlePaypalPayment} 
      disabled={isLoading}
            >
      {isLoading && <Spinner size="sm" />}
                        {isLoading ? 'Processing...' : 'Complete Payment'}
                
            </button>
    </div>
        )
    } else {
        return (
    <div className="w-full flex center justify-center">
            <div className="mt-10 flex justify-center rounded-md border border-transparent bg-[#FF0000] py-2 px-4 text-sm font-medium text-white shadow-sm">
                Select Payment Method to Continue
            </div>
    </div>
        )
    }
}



const handlePaypalPayment = async (): Promise<string> => {
  setIssubmitting(true);
  const serializedCartItems = JSON.stringify(cartItems);
  localStorage.setItem('cartItems', serializedCartItems);
  localStorage.setItem('cartSumTotal', overallSum.toString());

  const totalFreightAmount = parseFloat(localStorage.getItem('totalFreightAmount') || '0');

  const lineItems = cartItems.map(item => ({
      ingramPartNumber: item.ingramPartNumber,
      description: item.description,
      descr: null,
      price: item.price,
      vendorName: item.vendorName,
      quantity: String(item.quantity),
      warehouseId: String(item.warehouseId),
      image_url: item.image_url
  }));

  const distribution = [{ freightRate: totalFreightAmount }];

  const payload: CreateOrderPayload = {
      lineItems: {
          cartItems: lineItems,
          distribution: distribution,
          totalFees: 0,
          totalFreightAmount: totalFreightAmount,
          totalNetAmount: overallSum.toString(),
          totalTaxAmount: 0
      }
  };

  setIsLoading(true);

  try {
      const orderID = await createOrder(payload);
      console.log(orderID)
      if (orderID) {
        setIssubmitting(false);
          setPaypalIsOverlayVisible(true);
          setPayPalOrderId(orderID);
          return orderID;
      } else {
        setIssubmitting(false);
          toast.error("Could not initiate PayPal Checkout");
          setPaypalIsOverlayVisible(false);
          return '';
      }
  } catch (error) {
    setIssubmitting(false);
      toast.error("An error occurred while finalizing order details.");
      return '';
  } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
      setIssubmitting(false);
  }
};


// Function to handle PayPal payment verification
const handlePaypalPaymentVerify = async (orderID: string) => {
  setIsLoading(true);

  const payload = { orderID };

  try {
    const response = await ApiRequestService.callAPI<ResponseDataItem>(JSON.stringify(payload), "paypal_checkout/create_payment");
    const responseData = response.data;

    if (response.status === 200 && responseData.status === 'success') {
      // Handle success logic here
      console.log(JSON.stringify(responseData))
    } else {
      toast.error(responseData.message || "Verification failed.");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    toast.error("An error occurred while verifying payment details.");
  } finally {
    setIsLoading(false);
  }
};


async function createOrder(payload: CreateOrderPayload): Promise<string> {
  const response = await fetch(apiUrl+"paypal_checkout/create_payment", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(payload),
  });

  const order: CreateOrderResponse = await response.json();
  console.log("orderID "+JSON.stringify(order))
  return order.orderID;
}

async function onApprove(data: OnApproveData): Promise<void> {
  const response = await fetch(apiUrl+"paypal_checkout/create_payment", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
          orderID: data.orderID
      }),
  });

  const orderData: OnApproveResponse = await response.json();
  const name = orderData.payer.name.given_name;
  alert(`Transaction completed by ${name}`);
}


const handleCloseOverlay = () => {
    setIsOverlayVisible(false); // Hide the overlay
};




const initialValues = {
  cardNumber: '',
  cardName: '',
  expireDate: '',
  cvv: ''
};


const breadcrumbs = [
    { label: 'Home', href: '/' },
    { label: 'Cart', href: '/cart' },
    { label: 'Checkout', href: '/checkout' },
    { label: 'Payment', href: '/payment' },
     ];

  return (
    <main className="w-full overflow-hidden">
    <Header />
    <Container>
           <div className="flex flex-col gap-5 md:space-x-4 p-4">
              <div className="w-full mb-8">
                  <Breadcrumbs breadcrumbs={breadcrumbs} />
              </div>
              <div className="w-full flex flex-col gap-4">
                <p className="font-extrabold text-lg lg:text-2xl mb-4">Payment</p>
              </div>

              <div className="flex flex-col lg:flex-row gap-3 mt-4">

              <div className="flex-1 lg:w-[100%]   p-2">
                <div className="flex flex-col w-full">
                    <div className="font-bold text-[16px] mb-8">
                        Payment Method {scriptLoaded}
                    </div>


                            <div className="w-full">
                                <label className="radio-btn mt-4 mb-4 text-gray-600 font-bold cursor-pointer">
                                    <input
                                    type="radio"
                                    name="payment"
                                    
                                    id="card"
                                    className=""
                                    onChange={handleRadioChange}
                                    />
                                    <span></span>
                                    <Image src="/mastercard.png" alt="" width={36} height={24} /> Master Card
                                </label>
                            </div>

                            <div className="w-full">
                                <label className="radio-btn mt-4 mb-4 text-gray-600 font-bold cursor-pointer">
                                    <input
                                    type="radio"
                                    name="payment"
                                    id="paypal"
                                    className=""
                                    onChange={handleRadioChange}
                                    />
                                    <span></span>
                                    <Image src="/paypal.png" alt="" width={36} height={32} /> Paypal
                                </label>
                            </div>

                            <div className="w-full mt-8">
                                        {renderPaymentButton()}
                            </div>


                </div>


              </div>

              <div className="flex-1 lg:w-[40%] shadow-lg rounded-lg">
                <Summary 
                loadingEstimate={loadingEstimate} 
                errorMessage={errorIngramMessage}
                totalFreightAmount={totalFreightAmount}
                totalWeight={totalWeight}
                transitDays={transitDays}/>
                </div>


              </div>


          </div>


          {isOverlayVisible && (
          <div className="overlay">
            <div className="modal-content">
                <span className="close-button" onClick={closeOverlay}>Back</span>
                <div className="w-full">
                <EmbeddedCheckoutProvider stripe={stripePromise} options={{ clientSecret }}>
                    <EmbeddedCheckout />
                </EmbeddedCheckoutProvider>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          )}

       




    </Container>
    <ToastContainer />
    <Footer />
    {isPaypalOverlayVisible && (
          <div className="overlay">
            <div className="modal-content">
                <span className="close-button" onClick={closePaypalOverlay}>Back</span>
                <div className="w-full">
                <div className="mt-[4rem] nx-auto">
                
                <PayPalScriptProvider
            options={initialOptions}
          >
            <PayPalButtons
              style={{
                color: 'gold',
                shape: 'rect',
                label: 'pay',
                height: 50
              }}
              createOrder={handlePaypalPayment}
              onApprove={onApprove}
            />
          </PayPalScriptProvider>
         
                
                        </div>

                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
    </main>
  )
}

export default Payment


it appears PayPalScriptProvider is not loaded, hence the error
